# How to know if POST data is posted from within an Android App?

Tags: php, android, post

I am trying to identify the source of posted data in PHP and would like to verify if the date is being posted from within my Android App. Is there any way to verify this easily?

Comment: Set a field to a know value - `JHKJd76=bnwsdld7` unless someone is trying to spoof data, it wont contain the field

Comment: But they can analyze the posted data via Wireshark etc, and find out, right?

Comment: Communicate over SSL  - what problem are you having anyway - why do you need to ensure only your app can post data?

Comment: I am posting highscores of my game, and I want to verify that these are being posted from within the App

Comment: well SSL is probably going to be enough then, unless there is some financial reward for high scores. You could make it harder to spoof by encrypting the data yourself (as well as SSL), so a hacker would have to decompile your app as well as root their phone and perform a man in the middle attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify the data, I generate a checksum based on different values using my own algorithm. On the server side, I decode this to verify the posted data. This way, users cannot POST different data using the same checksum. They will need to know the algorithm.

Comment: That would do it. Still recommend SSL though - its not expensive nowdays